# Taking values from HTML form fails

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firebase

I want to use a JavaScript function to save values from an html form to a Firebase database.

The following code works (not using a form):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
        // Opmerking laten invullen
        var _klas = "testk";
        var _datum = new Date().getTime();

        // Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
        var postsRef = ref.child("opmerkingen");
        var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
            klas: _klas,
            datum: _datum
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Following code, using a form, doesn't work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
        <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
        function buttonPressed(event)
        {   
            var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
            // Opmerking laten invullen
            var _klas = document.getElementById("Klas").value;
            var _datum = new Date().getTime();

            // Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
            var postsRef = ref.child("opmerkingen");
            var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
                klas: _klas,
                datum: _datum
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method='post' action=''>
        <input type='text' name = 'Klas' id='Klas'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' onClick='buttonPressed(event)'>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong?

Added to question: changed code using onFormSubmitted

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
        <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
        function onFormSubmitted(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
            // Opmerking laten invullen
            var _klas = document.getElementById("Klas").value;
            var _datum = new Date().getTime();

            // Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
            var postsRef = ref.child("opmerkingen");
            var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
                klas: _klas,
                datum: _datum
            });

            // Get the unique ID generated by push()
            var postID = newPostRef.key();
        }

        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' action='' onsubmit="return onFormSubmitted(e)">
            <input type='text' name='Klas' id='Klas'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the behavior when clicking on the button? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nothing appears to go wrong, no error message. On clicking the field content is reset to blank as normal.

Comment: Have you checked the console? I get errors when using your code, and after fixing them, the problem is fixed.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/1XfkcOjkWEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that could really easily be solved by debugging in the console. Let's go step by step so you can see what is wrong.

If you open the console (generally F12, or in the developers tools), you'll see the messages and errors that the page generates. Let's start with your code (that I copied into a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hu6g0w6r/).

You are passing variable `e` (that is not defined anywhere) to the function. The JavaScript code fails there, and the browser continues submission normally. If you check the console, you'll see an error like:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Fine. Let's make that change. Update this line of code, and remove `e` ([see full code here](http://jsfiddle.net/hu6g0w6r/1/)):

```
<form method='post' action='' onsubmit="return onFormSubmitted()">
```

Try running again. And now you get a new error because `event` is not defined:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

This happens because the `event` is always present, and you don't need to define it in the function header (you are using an undefined `event` variable instead of the global `event` object). So just remove the reference in the function (but keep using the `event.preventDefault()`, [see the full code here](http://jsfiddle.net/hu6g0w6r/2/)):

```
function onFormSubmitted() {
```

And that's it! No more errors, and problem fixed.

---

The full code can be seen [in the last JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hu6g0w6r/2/), or here:

JS:

```
function onFormSubmitted() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
    // Opmerking laten invullen
    var _klas = document.getElementById("Klas").value;
    var _datum = new Date().getTime();

    // Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
    var postsRef = ref.child("opmerkingen");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
        klas: _klas,
        datum: _datum
    });

    // Get the unique ID generated by push()
    var postID = newPostRef.key();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='' onsubmit="return onFormSubmitted()">
    <input type='text' name='Klas' id='Klas'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

---

As a side note, you are returning the result of the function `onFormSubmitted()`, but that function is not returning any value. So you could change the onsubmit call to just `onsubmit="onFormSubmitted()"` [as seen on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hu6g0w6r/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "onClick", your `<form>` tag needs to listen to the "onsubmit" event.

```
<form method='post' action='' onsubmit="return onFormSubmitted(e)">
    <input type='text' name = 'Klas' id='Klas'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<script>
function onFormSubmitted(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    // get text input value 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that now but still nothing is stored. Maybe it's something small I overlook. I added the full code above in the question so it can be checked.

Comment: I did some more checking. Now I find that the values are actually passed correctly from the form, I even get a value for newPostRef.key() (calling an alert(postID) after that line). But still no data is added to the Firebase database??